# Unable to fit function convolved with NIntegrate with FindFit even with NumericQ

Tags: fitting

I am attempting to fit to the convolution of a simple function with a Gaussian.  (I realize this could be done with Convolve also, but I thought I could make it go faster this way).  I am able to define the function itself and the convolved version with

```
ExactFunction[x_, w_, h_, x0_] := h*UnitStep[x + w/2 - x0] UnitStep[w/2 - x + x0]
Gaussian[x_, δ_] := 1/(δ Sqrt[2 π]) E^(-x^2/(2 δ^2))
ConvolvedFunction[x_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ, δ_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[ ExactFunction[x - xp, w, h, x0]* Gaussian[xp, δ], {xp, -5 δ, 5 δ},  AccuracyGoal -> 4]
Show[Plot[ExactFunction[x, 50, 2, 50], {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
     Plot[ConvolvedFunction[x, 50, 2, 50, 5], {x, 0, 100}]]
```

where I have used ?NumericQ to prevent ConvolvedFunction from evaluating prematurely.  I can fit to the original function easily with something like

```
Data = Table[Sin[x π/100], {x, 0, 100}] + RandomReal[.2, 101];
FitParameters = FindFit[Data, ExactFunction[x, w, h, x0], {{w, 50}, {h, 1}, {x0, 50}}, x, 
                        Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
Show[ListPlot[Data],  Plot[ExactFunction[x, w, h, x0] /. FitParameters, {x, 0, 100}]]
```

However, if I try to fit the ConvolvedFunction even for small MaxIterations it never finishes.

```
ConvolvedFitParameters = FindFit[Data, ConvolvedFunction[x, w, h, x0, δ], 
            {{w, 81}, {h, .86}, {x0, 52}, {δ, 5}}, x, Method -> "PrincipalAxis", MaxIterations -> 10]
Show[ListPlot[Data], Plot[ConvolvedFunction[x, w, h, x0, δ] /. ConvolvedFitParameters, {x, 0, 100}]]
```

What have I done wrong?  I've looked at a number of similar examples and don't see any obvious differences.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: The solution provided by @belisarius works in the simple example I posted, but I think it is using the fact that the convolution of a Gaussian with a step function has a closed form.  My actual function is

```
VSumExact[x_, w_, CSum_, dposdx_, x0_ ] :=   
CSum/w (Log[1/4 (w + 2 dposdx (x - x0))^2] -
Log[1/4 (w - 2 dposdx (x - x0))^2])*UnitStep[w/2 - dposdx (x - x0)] 
UnitStep[dposdx (x - x0) + w/2]
```

and when I try to run

```
VSumSmooth[x_, w_, CSum_, dposdx_, x0_ , \[Delta]_] :=  
Evaluate@Convolve[Gaussian[xp, \[Delta]], 
VSumExact[xp, w, CSum, dposdx, x0], xp, x]
```

it never finished executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I eventually got this working with my actual function.  I think what I originally posted was correct (or close?), I just needed to set AccuracyGoal low enough.  Hopefully this helps anyone in a similar situation.

Setting up the convolved function:

```
BeamProfile[x_, \[Delta]_] := 
 1/(\[Delta] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) E^(-x^2/(2 \[Delta]^2))
VSumExact[x_, w_, CSum_, dposdx_, x0_ ] := 
 CSum/w (Log[1/4 (w + 2 dposdx (x - x0))^2] - 
 Log[1/4 (w - 2 dposdx (x - x0))^2])*
 UnitStep[w/2 - dposdx (x - x0)] UnitStep[dposdx (x - x0) + w/2]
VSumSmooth[x_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, CSum_?NumericQ, dposdx_?NumericQ,
 x0_ ?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[VSumExact[x - xp, w, CSum, dposdx, x0]*
 BeamProfile[xp, \[Delta]], {xp, -5 \[Delta], 5 \[Delta]}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 4]
Show[Plot[VSumExact[x, 50*10^-6, 5*10^-10, 2*10^-6, 25], {x, 0, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 Plot[VSumSmooth[x, 50*10^-6, 5*10^-10, 2*10^-6, 25, 1], {x, 0, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

Making initial guesses and running the fit:

```
Data = {-2.19919`*^-6, -7.23919`*^-7, -4.74143`*^-7, -3.80621`*^-7, \
 -1.00522`*^-6, -4.3233`*^-7, -1.15395`*^-6, -1.27838`*^-6, \
 -5.20207`*^-7, 7.19011`*^-7, 9.42227`*^-6, 0.0000329935`, 
 0.0000454738`, 0.0000394872`, 0.0000327209`, 0.0000260497`, 
 0.0000233109`, 0.0000195878`, 0.000016143`, 0.0000123143`, 
 9.57289`*^-6, 5.64377`*^-6, 2.82322`*^-6, 
 1.60046`*^-6, -1.14659`*^-6, -4.04984`*^-6, -7.78951`*^-6, \
 -0.000010962`, -0.0000138128`, -0.000015891`, -0.0000217059`, \
 -0.0000234981`, -0.0000276923`, -0.0000331199`, -0.0000422404`, \
 -0.000044107`, -0.0000282739`, -6.27234`*^-6, -1.18261`*^-6, \
 -1.71811`*^-6, -1.54246`*^-6, -2.24305`*^-6, -1.64444`*^-6, \
 -6.59291`*^-7, -2.06042`*^-6};
width = 50*10^-6; x0guess = 25; dposdxguess = 
 2*10^-6; \[Delta]guess = 1; CSumguess = -5*10^-10;
Show[ListPlot[Data, Mesh -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Position (a.u.)", "Signal (V)"}], 
Plot[VSumSmooth[x, width, CSumguess, dposdxguess, 
 x0guess, \[Delta]guess], {x, 0, 50}, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 PlotRange -> All]
SmoothFit = 
 FindFit[Data, 
 VSumSmooth[x, width, CSum, dposdx, 
 x0, \[Delta]], {{CSum, CSumguess}, {dposdx, dposdxguess}, {x0, 
 x0guess}, {\[Delta], \[Delta]guess}}, x, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
Show[Plot[
 VSumSmooth[x, width, CSum, dposdx, x0, \[Delta]] /. SmoothFit, {x, 
 0, 50}], 
ListPlot[Data, Mesh -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Position (a.u.)", "Signal (V)"}]]
```

[image]

```
{CSum->-4.06001*10^-10,dposdx->2.00797*10^-6,x0->24.4954,\[Delta]->1.08409}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
cf1[x_, w_, h_, x0_, δ_] :=  Evaluate@Convolve[Gaussian[xp, δ],  ExactFunction[xp, w, h, x0], xp, x]
ConvolvedFitParameters = FindFit[Data, cf1[x, w, h, x0, δ], {{w, 50}, {h, 1}, {x0, 50}, {δ, 5}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[Data], Plot[cf1[x, w, h, x0, δ] /. ConvolvedFitParameters, {x, 0, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Welp, that works, thanks!  I'll read up on Evaluate@.

Comment: Well, the elation was short lived -- in my actual code the function I am trying to convolve is a bit more complicated, and I can't even plot it after a few min, let alone fit to it.  I'll try optimizing it or writing the NIntegrate version in a similar form...